# How to control PlotLabels callout style?

Tags: plotting, labeling, style

When I work on a dark background (e.g. using **Format > Stylesheet > ReverseColor**) , some of the subtle stylings are not to my taste. A simple example can be reproduced (without changing the stylesheet):

```
Framed[
  Plot[{Sin@x, Cos@x}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"sin", "cos"}, Above, Style[#, Background -> Yellow] &]], 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

This shows that the embedding callout of `PlotLabels` are higher up in the hierarchy so the 3rd argument of `Placed` does not affect it.

How can I customize the callout used by `PlotLabels`?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to remove the underlying "gray" box? In that case, a hacky workaround is ``% /. Opacity[2/3] -> Opacity[0]``.

Comment: @Domen It may have unwanted effects. This way one cannot really control directly (or remove) the callout.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you check ``Charting`ChartLabelingDump`resolveCallout // PrintDefinitions``, you'll see a hard coded background color `GrayLevel[1, 2 / 3]`. I guess you can patch that function to solve the problem.

Comment: The logic seems to be: `Background` option from `Plot` is propagated to `resolveCallout`, if that's not a color (e.g. `Automatic` or `None`) then a default `GrayLevel[1, 2/3]` is used. So I guess it's acceptable to patch `resolveCallout`.